# How do i get the variable in a arraylist an set them to an label

Tags: java, arraylist

In my first class i got a method that looks like this

```
public Private HentLogindOplysninger(String Brugernavn){
    for(Private privat : privater){
        if(privat.getAccountName().equals(Brugernavn)){
            return privat;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

an in my main class i created my object in the top like this

```
private static PrivateRegistre PR = new PrivateRegistre();
```

i call it

```
PR.HentLogindOplysninger(KundeId);
```

but how do I get private and separates it, and put the different variable in each label?

Comment: What label are you talking about?

Comment: please this question is about ..., for better help post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable,

Comment: please, read Java Code Convention http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: Not sure what is your question? Also if possible please give english version of code, as that would be readble by many other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this you want?

```
final Private myPrivate = PR.HentLogindOplysninger(KundeId);
```